# Probability in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, probability

Do you need to take a probability/statistics course for Quantum Mechanics, or is the [probability in quantum mechanics](http://www.google.com/search?q=probability+quantum+mechanics) so rudimentary that you can just learn it along the way? I'm in doubt as to whether I should take the course or not, is it needed? What probability is actually in QM?

What I know already:

Arithmetic mean, median, mode, sample & population variance, standard deviation, discrete and continuous random variables, binomial, poisson and gaussiand distribution and finally the expected value.

If you would like to add things I need which aren't listed, that would be wonderful. I'd hate taking the course knowing almost everything I need apart from a couple of things.

Answer (score 3):

The probability theory you need to start studying QM is very rudimentary.  You need to know what a probability distribution is, the concept of normalization and mean (expectation value).  That's about it.  When I studied it at Uni, the physics lecturers briefly introduced the concepts for people who hadn't studied stats.  It can't have taken more than half an hour to describe.

Comment: So you would say I'm set already? This is my current knowledge of statistics/probability: Arithmetic mean, median, mode, sample & population variance, standard deviation, discrete and continuous random variables, binomial, poisson and gaussiand distribution and finally the expected value.

Comment: That's more than enough knowledge of stats to learn QM!